SQL to return unique rows
I am trying to write a query against a table in SQL Server where I only want to return unique rows. The table has ItemId, Dept, and ItemCount. The question is to filter on ItemCount where the value is between 1000 and 8000. This ok! The thing is that whilst all three columns are needed, only one Dept name needs to returned. In other words, if Dept A has ItemId 1234 and ItemId 5678 along ItemCount 801 and ItemCount 7654, then only one of these rows needs to be returned. Which one is not important.
So, I have tried a sub query on returning rows between 1000 and 8000, and then distinct on rest.
How do I filter out so I only see one Dept A, B and C?

"I have tried a sub query ..."  Where???  We don't see a single query on this post.

Your question is very poorly asked, but that will take time as you go along.  Providing sample data of what you have and also what you are expecting out of it are also better.
Now you question, from my interpretation, you could have 100 items that have a count within the range in question.  Why do you only want 1, especially if it is across different items and even different departments.
Anyhow, I think what you MIGHT be looking for is the TOP command to only return 1 row, and you don't care what row it is, as long as it qualifies your criteria.
Select top 1 
      YT.*
   from 
      YourTable YT
   where
          YT.ItemCount >= 1000
      AND YT.ItemCount <= 8000

So this will return all columns from whatever 'YourTable' is based on the critiera.  As soon as it finds the first qualifier, thats what you get.
I would suggest more claification by editing your existing posted question with more details and then letting me (or anyone in the future) of updates vs trying to reply what could be lengthy in a comment line.
